# How to get a list of shared mailboxes for a user in ews-java-api?

Tags: exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

Currently, I am able to access the shared mailbox of a user account if I already know the address of the shared mailbox. However, if I know just the user account details (but not the shared mailboxes it has access to), how can I retrieve the list of shared mailboxes linked to this user account in ews-java-api?

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "pwd");
service.setCredentials(credentials);
service.setUrl(new URI("https://xyz/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));

Mailbox mailbox = new Mailbox("sharedMailboxAddress");
FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, mailbox);

FolderView folderView = new FolderView(20);
FindFoldersResults results = service.findFolders(folderId, folderView);
```

Here is the link to ews-java-api --> https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find an answer to this question?

Comment: No, but currently I am able to access the shared mailbox of a user account if I already know the address of the shared mailbox.